# How do I speed up an update in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm running on update to a table (Table_A) that has 9.5 million records.  I've been running it for 13 hours and it still hasn't finished!  Can someone point me in the right direction in terms of how to speed it up?  I can use PL/SQL to store the sub-selects into variables if that would make it faster.  I'm an Oracle newbie and would appreciate any help.

```
update Table_A
set STATUS='DELETED', DESC='REDACTED', NAME=dbms_random.string('A', 20)
where Table_B_ID in (
    select ID
    from Table_B
    where Table_C_ID in (
        select ID
        from Table_C
        where XYZ_ID!=56
    )
);
```

Table_A has 9.5 million records
Table_B has 430,000 records
Table_C has 3050 recoreds

Comment: Show us the execution plan

Answer (score 1):

Try to write both subqueries using EXISTS instead of an in-list. It is much more performant.

See here for a discussion: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684

**EDIT 2015-03-02**
Here is a (hopefully correct) query using exists:

```
UPDATE Table_A A
   SET A.STATUS='DELETED', A.DESC='REDACTED', A.NAME=dbms_random.string('A', 20)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM Table_B B
     WHERE A.Table_B_ID = B.ID
       AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
          FROM Table_C C
         WHERE C.XYZ_ID!=56
           AND B.Table_C_ID = C.ID
       )
 );
```

Comment: I am guessing that the optimizer will rewrite the `IN`s as `EXISTS`

Comment: I'm not totally sure if the optimizer can do that, but he totally should. But using exists (and appropriate indices) saved me when I had a similar performance problem...

Comment: I agree that `EXISTS` would be better and more readable. But I think the ultimate problem is indexes (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

first create index on table_b for Table_C_ID,

then create the statistics of the 3 tables,

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('OWNER', 'TABLE_A');
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('OWNER', 'TABLE_B');
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('OWNER', 'TABLE_C');
```

after that use paralell hint:

```
update /*+parallel(8)*/Table_A
set STATUS='DELETED', DESC='REDACTED', NAME=dbms_random.string('A', 20)
where Table_B_ID in (
    select ID
    from Table_B
    where Table_C_ID in (
        select ID
        from Table_C
        where XYZ_ID!=56
    )
);
```

those will increase the speed much better

Answer (score 0):

How long is the corresponding `select`?

```
select a.*
from Table_A
where Table_B_ID in (select ID
                     from Table_B
                     where Table_C_ID in (select ID
                                          from Table_C
                                          where XYZ_ID <> 56
                                         )
                    );
```

Presumably, this is not fast, and my guess is that it is not fast because of the lack of indexes.  For this query, I would recommend the following composite indexes:  `table_b(Table_C_ID, ID)` and `table_c(xyz_id, id)`.  I would recommend that you get the `select` working fast before working on the `update`.

Note that this is just a guess. For example, you could be updating every row in `Table_A`, which is a real performance hog.  Or, there could be locks on one or more tables causing contention for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.  I'm trying them one at a time.

Apparently using `exists` is not the same as `in` in all cases.  For example, the below query returns different results if I replace `in` with `exists`:

```
update Table_A
set STATUS='DELETED', DESC='REDACTED', NAME=dbms_random.string('A', 20)
where exists (
    select ID
    from Table_B
    where exists (
        select ID
        from Table_C
        where XYZ_ID!=56
    )
);
```

Comment: I realized there is a difference because I'm not building the query right.

Comment: Yes, you must join in the IDs too, otherwise the select will not be the same. And by the way: you should edit your original entry, and not add an answer for follow-up questions... (see my edit in the upvoted answer for help)